# youtube data api upload via video url

Tags: java, youtube-data-api

Is there a way to upload videos to YouTube via **YouTube Data API v3** by providing the URL to the video which is stored in my Google Cloud Storage.

I am looking for something similar to Facebook Graph API's me/videos?file_url=MY_VIDEO_URL.

I know it is possible by creating an InputStream from the URL, but Facebooks method is much faster and best for my scenario.

Comment: Did you find a solution Thanthu?

Comment: @Josir sorry but had no luck at the time. This requirement was later removed from my project so stopped looking for solutions.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to use Google Functions (similar to AWS Lambda). If the solution works, I will try to remember to post here.